# Retrofit insert to room repository but only insert one row

Tags: android-studio, mvvm, retrofit, android-room

I think is right but always insert one row, I don't know why? I'm user MVVM, dependency injection (Kodein), and Coroutin

(interface)
MyApi.kt

```
@GET("param-list-all")
suspend fun getParamterALL() : Response<List<AllParam>>
```

(class)
Provinsi.kt

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["id"])
data class Provinsi(
    val createdBy: String?,
    val createdDate: Long?,
    val id: Int?,
    val provinceCode: String?,
    val provinceName: String?,
    val updatedBy: String?,
    val updatedDate: Long?
)
```

ProvinsiRepo.kt

```
class ProvinsiRepo(
    private val api: MyApi,
    private val db: AppDatabase
) : SafeApiRequest(){
suspend fun getAllProvinsiAPI(): List<Provinsi> {
    return apiRequest{
        api.getProvinsi()
    }
}

suspend fun saveallParam(param: List<Provinsi>) = db.getProvinsiDao().upsert(param)
}
```

ProvinsiViewModel.kt

```
class ProvinsiViewModel(
    private val provinsirepo: ProvinsiRepo,  
) : ViewModel() {

   provinsirepo.getAllProvinsiAPI().let { provinsi->
          provinsirepo.saveallParam(provinsi)
   }
```

DAO

```
@Dao
interface AllParamDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsert(parameter: List<AllParam>)

}
```

Comment: sorry wrong MyApi.kt

Comment: @GET("list-province")
    suspend fun getProvinsi() : Response<List<Provinsi>>

Answer (score 0):

It might happen if the List returned by the API request always has the same id in the Provinsi object. If it is the same, then it will replace data in the DB because id is the primary key and it will maintain the UNIQUE constraint.

To fix this, you can try:

```
@Entity
data class Provinsi(
    val createdBy: String?,
    val createdDate: Long?,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0, // use this line
    val provinceCode: String?,
    val provinceName: String?,
    val updatedBy: String?,
    val updatedDate: Long?
)
```